# Entity Framework Code First - Navigation property on Composite Primaty Key

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-5, firebird2.5

- Firebird 2.5
- Entity Framework 5
- FirebirdClientDll 3.0.0.0

Hi, I'm trying to access my legacy database with the Entity Framework (Code First). 
I got the problem that the database does not use foreign keys...

```
public class CUSTOMERS
{
    public int CUSTOMERID { get; set; }
    public string NAME{ get; set; }
}

public class INVOICES
{
    public int INVOICEID{ get; set; }
    public int CUSTOMERID{ get; set; }

    public virtual CUSTOMERS CUSTOMERS { get; set; }
}

public class INVOICEContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<CUSTOMERS> CUSTOMERS{ get; set; }
    public DbSet<INVOICES> INVOICES{ get; set; }

    public INVOICEContext(DbConnection connectionString) : base(connectionString, false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<INVOICEContext>(null);
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();

        /*modelBuilder.Entity<INVOICES>().HasRequired(b => b.CUSTOMERS)
                    .WithMany()
                    .Map(p => p.MapKey("INVOICEID"));*/ //Doesn't work because INVOICEID is defined

        modelBuilder.Entity<INVOICES>().HasKey(a => new { a.INVOICEID, a.CUSTOMERID});
        modelBuilder.Entity<CUSTOMERS>().HasKey(a => new { a.CUSTOMERID });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

Normally I could remove the property `CUSTOMERID` from the class `INVOICES`, but in this case it is part of the primary key...

I found many threads which suggested to use `IsIndependent`, but it seems to be [removed from the Entity Framework 5 (or 4.1)](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/285bc785-d884-4342-bfcf-a33847139501/).

I hope you can understand my poor English and maybe give me a hint what I'm doing wrong ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you mean with "*the database does not use foreign keys*". So, maybe the following is not the answer you are looking for. But I'd say that you can use your relationship mapping that is commented out in your code if you replace `...MapKey...` by `HasForeignKey` and use `CUSTOMERID` instead of `INVOICEID` as the foreign key property:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<INVOICES>()
    .HasRequired(b => b.CUSTOMERS)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(b => b.CUSTOMERID);
```

The model and the rest of the mapping is fine in my opinion. Your relationship is an *identifying relationship* (that means that the foreign key is part of a composite primary key) which is a valid mapping with Entity Framework.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that but the property CUSTOMERS is always null. With "does not use foreign keys" I mean that there are no foreign keys defined in the database (leagacy).

Comment: OMG, I used the wrong database. It works now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Try this ...

```
modelBuilder.Entity<INVOICES>()
      .HasRequired(i => i.CUSTOMERS)
      .WithMany()
      .HasForeignKey(i => i.CUSTOMERID);
```

Comment: Same as above, the CUSTOMERS property is always null... Does this also work without defined Foreign Keys in the database?

Comment: OMG, I used the wrong database. It works now. Thank you so much!